# Setting multiple background colors to H1

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have searched many similar questions on SO but haven't gotten the result that I want exactly. I want similar like this:

[image: screenshot]

I want to style two different lines with different BG colors

I tried with this style

```css
h1.g1-mega.g1-mega-1st.entry-title:first-line {background:#ffd334;}
h1.g1-mega.g1-mega-1st.entry-title:last-line {background:#ddd;}
```

```html
<h1 class="g1-mega g1-mega-1st entry-title" itemprop="headline">Top 25 Wild Bird Photographs of the Week: Mountain Birds </h1>
```

please check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/behance_in/wj4ctf5m/)

the second line CSS is not working.

[image: see screenshot]

Comment: It is impossible to implement exactly as on the screenshot without wrapping part of the text into another tag.

Comment: It is not possible. You have to put them in difference span at least.

Answer (score 3):

```css
span:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}

span:last-child {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 1.8;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>Top 25 Wild Bird Photographs</span><br>
    <span>of the Week: Mountain Birds </span>
</h1>
```

Comment: As I understand author want to achieve that effect without additional tags

Comment: You may be correct, but I didn't see that requirement in the question. @flppv

Answer (score 0):

```
h1.g1-mega {background:#ddd;}
h1.g1-mega:first-line {background:#ffd334;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `last-line` selector - so you options is to set style for the `h1` and override the *first line* with the `first-line` selector:

```css
h1.g1-mega.g1-mega-1st.entry-title {background:#ddd;}
h1.g1-mega.g1-mega-1st.entry-title:first-line {background:#ffd334;}
```

```html
<h1 class="g1-mega g1-mega-1st entry-title" itemprop="headline">
Top 25 Wild Bird Photographs of the Week: Mountain Birds 
</h1>
```

---

Note that not all properties work with `first-line` selector - see a list of properties [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line#Allowable_properties):

> Only a small subset of CSS properties can be used with the
> ::first-line pseudo-element:
>
> All font-related properties: font, font-kerning, font-style,
> font-variant, font-variant-numeric, font-variant-position,
> font-variant-east-asian, font-variant-caps, font-variant-alternates,
> font-variant-ligatures, font-synthesis, font-feature-settings,
> font-language-override, font-weight, font-size, font-size-adjust,
> font-stretch, and font-family
>
> All background-related properties:
> background-color, background-clip, background-image,
> background-origin, background-position, background-repeat,
> background-size,  background-attachment, and background-blend-mode
>
> The color property
>
> word-spacing, letter-spacing, text-decoration,
> text-transform, and line-height
>
> text-shadow, text-decoration,
> text-decoration-color, text-decoration-line, text-decoration-style,
> and vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

```css
span {
  padding: 10px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
}

span:first-child {
  background-color: yellow
}

span:last-child {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>Top 25 Wild Bird Photographs</span>
  <span>of the Week: Mountain Birds </span>
</h1>
```